# In alfresco, is it possible to traverse child Associations in freemarker when using java backed controllers for webscripts?

Tags: alfresco

Am I correct in assuming that one can only walk the childAssocs tree of an object put into the model when a javascript controller is used to dump the object in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can also add a NodeRef to the model in your java controller, e.g.:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("folder", folderNodeRef);
return model;
```

afaik a nodeRef is automatically evaluated to a TemplateNode when passed to your ftl:

```
<#list folder.children as child>
 .....
</#list>
```

Comment: Then there must be some other reason I am unable to traverse the association tree.

Comment: Try ${folder.class.name} to see whether what you have in the template really is a TemplateNode.